# How to update embedded objects in spring mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am working a simple Spring MongoDB implementation.

My Entities look like this:

```
@Document(collection = "Book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;  // Note: This should be BinInt, String or ObjectId
    private List<Author> author;
    @Indexed  // Note: On which fields we write where clause
    private String bookName;
    private int price;
    private int rating;
    private Date publishedDate;
    private Map<String, String> contentIndex = new HashMap<>();
    private List<String> tags;
    private Publisher publisher;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Book(ObjectId id, List<Author> author, String bookName, String firstName, String lastName, int price, int rating, Date publishedDate, Map<String, String> contentIndex, List<String> tags, Publisher publisher) {

}

@Data
public class Publisher {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int bookCount;
    private Date dob;
    private String email;
    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Publisher(ObjectId id, String firstName, String lastName, int bookCount, Date dob, String email) {

}

@Data
public class Author {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private int bookCount;
    private Date dob;
    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Author(ObjectId id, String firstName, String lastName, int bookCount, Date dob) 
}
```

I am able to do all basic CRUD operations on BooK object by just extending the MongoRepositoy.
Now I am trying to do the same CRUD operations on embedded objects Publisher and array of Authors in the BooK object.

I am trying to do this but have not found a solution. I went through the Spring MongoDB documentation about Query and Update and several Stack Overflow questions. But not able to do it till now.

I am wanting to do the following things:

- how to update field values in book.publisher object.
- how to update book.authors[1] fields.
- how to add new author to book.authors list object.

Answer (score 0):

**How to update field values in book.publisher object.**

```
public void updatePublisher(BigInteger bookId, Publisher publisher) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(bookId));
    Book book;
    book = mongoTemplate.findOne
            (query, Book.class);
    Update update = new Update();
    if (publisher.getFirstName() != null)
        update.set("publisher.firstName", publisher.getFirstName());
    if (publisher.getLastName() != null)
        update.set("publisher.lastName", publisher.getLastName());
    if (publisher.getBookCount() != null)
        update.set("publisher.bookCount", publisher.getBookCount());
    if (publisher.getEmail() != null)
        update.set("publisher.email", publisher.getEmail());
    mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, Book.class);
}
```

**How to update book.authors[1] fields.**

```
public void updateAuthor(BigInteger bookId, Author author) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(bookId));
    Book book;
    book = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Book.class);
    Author old = null;
    if (book != null) {
        List<Author> al = book.getAuthors().getAuthors();
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size() && index == -1; i++) {
            if (author.getId().equals(al.get(i).getId()))
                index = i;
        }
        if (index > -1) {
            old = book.getAuthors().getAuthors().get(index);
            book.getAuthors().getAuthors().remove(index);
            book.getAuthors().getAuthors().add(author); // Note: If you need merge of new object to old then , copy field by field from new object to old object.
            mongoTemplate.save(book);
        }

    }
}
```

**How to add new author to book.authors list object.**

```
  public Author addAuthor(BigInteger bookId, Author author) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(bookId));
        Book book;
        book = mongoTemplate.findOne
                (query, Book.class);

        if (book != null) {
            book.getAuthors().getAuthors().add(author);
            mongoTemplate.save(book);
        }
        return author;
    }
```

I implemented and working well. However, I am open to optimising this if possible.